# Cannot acces Tomcat Server from outside LAN network

Tags: tomcat

I'm seeking for some help with a Tomcat Server.

I got an OVH server ( Windows 2012 R2 ) with 2 networks interfaces :

- WAN ( 151.X.X.X
- LAN ( 172.16.0.0 )

These two URLs work !

**http://172.16.0.6:8080/iComTest/servlet/conn**

**http://localhost:8080/iComTest/servlet/conn**

But I need to access throught **151.X.X.X/iComTest/servlet/conn** ! And it doesn't works !

My server.xml :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           address="0.0.0.0"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

**Furthermore, I set an inbound rule in the windows firewall allowing the port 8080 !**

When I do a nmap scan, I got this : **8080/tcp filtered http-proxy**

So I'm really confused.

I really appreciate some help on that topic !

Best regards,

Hugo

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding two different IP-s to your tomcat configuration.

Like this :

```
<Connector address="LAN" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" /> 

<Connector address="WAN" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but infortunately, it doesn't works ! Moreover, http://localhost:8080/iComTest/servlet/conn doesn't works anymore. Best regards, Hugo

Comment: I suppose you can try running tomcat instance on 0.0.0.0 and try port scan your WAN IP, port 8080.